# How can I detect when the user clicks on a hyperlink in a WebView control?

Tags: c#, windows, webview, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm trying to detect when the user clicks on a hyperlink in a WebView control from Windows 10. Is there any way to detect this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to catch the click itself you'll need to do that from inside the web page's JavaScript. Depending on where the page comes from you may be able to inject JavaScript code to do so with [WebView.InvokeScriptAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx)

If you want to detect the navigation triggered by the click then you can handle the [WebView.NavigationStarting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting.aspx) or [NavigationCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationcompleted.aspx) events.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 I would use the `WebView.NewWindowRequested` event:

```
private void WebView1_NewWindowRequested(WebView sender, WebViewNewWindowRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(args.Uri);
    args.Handled = true; // Prevent the browser from being launched.
}
```