# Windows Phone Webview change userAgent

Tags: c#, webview, windows-phone

How do i change the user Agent for Windows Phone Webview permanently?

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        string ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 6 Build/LYZ28E) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.20 Mobile Safari/537.36";
        HttpRequestMessage hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, homeUri);
        hrm.Headers.Add("User-Agent", ua);
        webView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(hrm);
    }
```

It works till the webpage loads, but if I open a subpage in the webview it uses the standard user agent.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: [Changing the user agent of the WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937573/changing-the-user-agent-of-the-webbrowser-control)

Another possible solution could be intercept the click event and change the HttpRequest message, see here: [How can I detect when the user clicks on a hyperlink in a WebView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092642/how-can-i-detect-when-the-user-clicks-on-a-hyperlink-in-a-webview-control)

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Webbrowser was not an option since i am using a webview

but the click intercepting worked. Many Thanks